# ipad - sliding menus on a view based app

Tags: iphone

I have a view based app and I would like to implement one of those sliding menus (I don't know if there's a specific name to call them), like Mail.

The idea is this: I have a board with several objects. When the user taps and hold on a object for half a second a popover appears showing the object properties. The properties are: object color, object text, object text color and object shadow color.

Every of these 4 properties, when tapped, will make a new window slide from right into the popover, bringing the adjustments. Tap done and the view is pushed to the right bringing the first view again... the process repeats for all views.

how do I add these "sliding menus" to a view based app inside a popover?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about iPhone or iPad? Your tag is only for iPhone.

On the iPad, there's a specific UI element called a Popover. When you click on the "Reply" icon in Mail, a menu appears with "Reply" and "Forward". This is a Popover. On iPhone, there's another kind of UI element, used for example when you want to copy text. It shows "Select", "Cut" and so on. That's called a Callout. Note that you can't use Popovers on the iPhone.

If you're talking about Mail on the iPhone, you have to find out how to use a `UINavigationController`, and then use the method `-pushViewController:animated:` to make a new page slide onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

its the default animation for UINavigationController. so if you implement a UINavigationController as your root view for your UIPopoverController, then push the view controllers you want, it should be the desired effect.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo on my question... I have a view based app. How do I do that? any code you can point to? thanks.

Comment: you can still have a uinavigationcontroller as the root view of the popovercontroller.

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property ( nonatomic , retain )  IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender;

-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons;
```

.m

```
@synthesize scrollView;



-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom called");


    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;


    if (button.tag == 0) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked first button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
    }
    else if (button.tag == 1) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked second button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);

    }
    // ......like this

    NSLog(@"button clicked is : %iBut \n\n",button.tag);



}       



-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons{

for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfButtons; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with image

        //OR

    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%iBut",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title

    button.frame = CGRectMake(i*(offset+buttonSize.width), 8.0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);

    button.clipsToBounds = YES;

    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;//half of the width

    button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

    button.tag=i;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

}

self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake((buttonSize.width + offset) * totalNoOfButtons, buttonSize.height);

    //self.navigationItem.titleView=self.scrollView;//if u have navigationcontroller then enable this line
```

}

**Dont forget to connect the scrollView in interface builder**

**while creating the scrollview in IB make sure ur scrollView height is 44.which is default to navigation bar.so it will look nice.**

```
in viewDidLoad call 

[self createMenuWithButtonSize:CGSizeMake(70.0, 30.0) withOffset:20.0f noOfButtons:30];
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]